# Mern Stack application mongoose error or callback function depricated

Tags: mongodb, express, npm, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

[Mongoose throws this error when starting npm at backend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqCTM.png)

```
`const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoURI = '<MONGO_URL_USED>'
module.exports = function (callback) {
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true }, async (err, result) => {
        if (err) console.log("---" + err)
        else {
            // var database =
            console.log("connected to mongo")
            const foodCollection = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("food_items");
            foodCollection.find({}).toArray(async function (err, data) {
                const categoryCollection = await mongoose.connection.db.collection("Categories");
                categoryCollection.find({}).toArray(async function (err, Catdata) {
                    callback(err, data, Catdata);
                })
            });
        }
    })
};
```

`
I tried putting the connection call in a variable and declaring the function async but still it shows this error.